# Issues in remove comma in javascript

Tags: javascript

When i entered only one email id, and check in inspecter, it shows like this

I need to remove commas,if i enter only one id and it need to show commas, if i enter one more or multiple id's given it shows comma. Can you please help ?

```
function GetTextValue() {

    $(divValue).empty(); 
    $(divValue).remove(); values = '';
    values += this.value + ','
    });
    document.all.contact_list.value = values;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function GetTextValue() {
    $(divValue).empty();
    $(divValue).remove(); 
    var values = '';

    $('.input').each(function() {
        divValue = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
            padding:'5px', width:'200px'
        });
        if(this.value.trim() != ''){
            if(values != ''){
                values += ',';
            }
            values += this.value.trim();
        }
    });
    document.all.contact_list.value = values;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like that.

```
function GetTextValue() {

    $(divValue).empty(); 
    $(divValue).remove(); values = '';

    $('.input').each(function() {
        divValue = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
            padding:'5px', width:'200px'
        });
        if (this.value == '') {
           // alert('Empty');
        } else if (values != '') {
            values += ',';
        }
        values += this.value;
    });
    document.all.contact_list.value = values;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpy5g7zL/)

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Alert if `this.value` is empty ??

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if (this.value != '')` - he only wants to add commas if there is another value, so checking if values is not empty will add extra commas on the end

Comment: is this right?  if (values != '') {
   alert('text');
        values += ',';
   } thanks

Comment: sorry, how to test, if i enter more email id with using alert? thanks

Comment: @rish I added JSFiddle link to test it. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74805/discussion-between-rish-and-arkar-aung).

Comment: I have seen your link.. but i just confused how can i add with my code? thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetTextValue() {
    $(divValue).empty();
    $(divValue).remove(); 
    var values = '';

    $('.input').each(function() {
        divValue = $(document.createElement('div')).css({padding:'5px', width:'200px'});
       if(this.value != '') {
           values += this.value;
           values += ',';
       }
    });
    document.all.contact_list.value = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);//remove last comma
}
```

Comment: It will be ended with comma like `a,b,c,`